# Probability that exactly $n$ trials are required is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$

Tags: probability-theory

> Independent trials that result in a success with probability $p$ are
>   successively performed until a total of $k$ successes is obtained.
>   Show that the probability that exactly $n$ trials are required is
>
> $$\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Let $A$ be the event that $k$ successes occur in $n$ trials. Then $P(A) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.  Now, let $B$ be the event that exactly $n$ trials are required to obtain $k$ successes (as in the problem statement above). Then $P(B) = \binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$.
Since $P(B) \cdot \frac{n}{k} = P(A)$, I was thinking maybe that could lead to a proof.

How $A$ is different from $B$? For example, is there a formal way to state this, such as $B = \overline{A} \cap \dots$.)

I'm not looking for the answer, just some hints please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see how $A$ is different from $B$:

Suppose that $k=3$ and $n=5$. If S is a success and F is a failure, SSSFF, SSFSF, SFSSF, and FSSSF all count towards $A$ but not towards $B$. The strings that count towards $A$ are those that have $3$ S’s and $2$ F’s; the ones that count towards $B$ are those that have $3$ S’s and $2$ F’s **and end with an S**.

Comment: Aha, because the trials continue *until* $k$ successes have occurred, which implies that the **S** must be the last, $n$th trial.

Comment: @mathMajor: Exactly. So you know what the outcome of the $n$-th trial is, and as André said, you must have the other $k-1$ successes distributed amongst the first $n-1$ trials.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** In order for the $k$-th success to occur on the $n$-th trial, we must have exactly $k-1$ successes in the first $n-1$ trials, and then a success on the $n$-th trial.